# Timing issue for lyrics in midi files

Tags: c++, qt, hex, midi

I have created basic application for detecting timing for lyrics using QT c++. And it works correctly for most of midi files. (I checked it with 3rd parties program). But it not working for some midi files. First thought that midi files corrupted, BUT that midi file opens correctly it 3rd parties program (correct timing for lyrics timing). I have no idea what's wrong, maybe I missed something

This is code from main.cpp:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDebug>
struct TempoChange {
    quint32 position;
    quint64 tempo;
};

QList<TempoChange> tempoMap;

void detectTempoMap(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qWarning("Could not open file");
        return;
    }

    QDataStream in(&file);
    in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);  // MIDI files are big-endian

    quint32 headerId;
    quint32 headerSize;
    quint16 formatType;
    quint16 trackCount;
    quint16 division;

    // Read header chunk
    in >> headerId >> headerSize >> formatType >> trackCount >> division;

    // Check that the header ID is 'MThd'
    if (headerId != 0x4D546864) {
        qWarning("Not a valid MIDI file");
        return;
    }

    // Process each track chunk
    for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; ++i) {
        quint32 trackId;
        quint32 trackSize;

        // Read track header
        in >> trackId >> trackSize;

        // Check that the track ID is 'MTrk'
        if (trackId != 0x4D54726B) {
            qWarning("Not a valid track chunk");
            return;
        }

        // Read track data
        QByteArray trackData = file.read(trackSize);

        // Process track data
        QDataStream trackStream(trackData);
        trackStream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);

        quint32 position = 0;
        quint32 deltaTime = 0;
        quint8 statusByte;
        quint8 lastStatusByte = 0; // Added for running status

        while (!trackStream.atEnd()) {
            // Read delta time
            quint8 byte;
            trackStream >> byte;
            deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);
            while (byte & 0x80) {
                trackStream >> byte;
                deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);
            }
            position += deltaTime;
            // Peek at the next byte without advancing the position in the stream
            QByteArray peeked = trackStream.device()->peek(1);
            if (!peeked.isEmpty()) {
                byte = peeked[0];
            }
            if (byte >= 0x80) {
                // This is a status byte, so read it
                trackStream >> statusByte;
                lastStatusByte = statusByte; // Remember this status byte for running status
            } else {
                // This is not a status byte, so use the last status byte
                statusByte = lastStatusByte;
            }

            // Check if this is a meta event
            if (statusByte == 0xFF) {
                quint8 metaType;
                quint8 length;
                // Read meta event type and length
                trackStream >> metaType >> length;
                // Process meta event based on type
                switch (metaType) {
                    case 0x51: {  // Set Tempo event
                        quint8 byte1, byte2, byte3;
                        trackStream >> byte1 >> byte2 >> byte3;
                        quint64 tempo = (byte1 << 16) | (byte2 << 8) | byte3;
                        tempoMap.append({position, tempo});
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        trackStream.skipRawData(length);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            deltaTime = 0;
        }
    }
}

quint64 getActualTempo(quint64 position)
{
    for(int i=(tempoMap.length()-1);i>=0;i--) {
        if(position >= tempoMap.at(i).position) {
            return tempoMap.at(i).tempo;
        }
    }
    return tempoMap.at(0).tempo;
}

quint64 readMidiFileContent(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return true;
    }

    QDataStream in(&file);
    in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);  // MIDI files are big-endian

    quint32 headerId;
    quint32 headerSize;
    quint16 formatType;
    quint16 trackCount;
    quint16 division;

    // Read header chunk
    in >> headerId >> headerSize >> formatType >> trackCount >> division;
    // Check that the header ID is 'MThd'
    if (headerId != 0x4D546864) {
        file.close();
        return true;
    }
    quint64 tempo = 500000; // default tempo 120 bpm
    quint64 generalTiming = 0;
    quint8 lastStatusByte = 0; // Added for running status

    for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; ++i) {
        quint32 trackId;
        quint32 trackSize;

        // Read track header
        in >> trackId >> trackSize;

        // Check that the track ID is 'MTrk'
        if (trackId != 0x4D54726B) {
            file.close();
            return true;
        }

        // Read track data
        QByteArray trackData = file.read(trackSize);

        // Process track data
        QDataStream trackStream(trackData);
        trackStream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);

        quint64 deltaTime = 0;
        quint64 totalDeltaTime = 0;
        quint8 statusByte;

        while (!trackStream.atEnd()) {
            // Read delta time
            quint8 byte;
            trackStream >> byte;
            deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);
            while (byte & 0x80) {
                trackStream >> byte;
                deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);
            }
            totalDeltaTime += deltaTime;

            // Peek at the next byte without advancing the position in the stream
            QByteArray peeked = trackStream.device()->peek(1);
            if (!peeked.isEmpty()) {
                byte = peeked[0];
            }
            if (byte >= 0x80) {
                // This is a status byte, so read it
                trackStream >> statusByte;
                lastStatusByte = statusByte; // Remember this status byte for running status
            } else {
                // This is not a status byte, so use the last status byte
                statusByte = lastStatusByte;
            }

            // Check if this is a meta event
            if (statusByte == 0xFF) {
                quint8 metaType;
                quint8 length;

                // Read meta event type and length
                trackStream >> metaType >> length;
                switch (metaType) {
                    case 0x05:
                    case 0x01: {
                        QByteArray textData = trackData.mid(trackStream.device()->pos(), length);
                        QString text = QString::fromLatin1(textData);
                        if(deltaTime > 0 || (text == "\n" || text == "\r" || text == "\n\r" || text == "\r\n")) {
                            tempo = getActualTempo(totalDeltaTime);
                            // Convert delta time to milliseconds

                            quint64 time = (1.0*deltaTime/division)*(tempo/1000.0);
                            generalTiming += time;
                            qDebug()<<text<<"-"<<time;
                        }
                        trackStream.skipRawData(length);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        trackStream.skipRawData(length);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            deltaTime = 0;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return generalTiming;
}

bool readMidiFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    detectTempoMap(fileName);
    if(tempoMap.length() == 0) {
        //put default tempo 120 bpm
        tempoMap.append({0, 500000});
    }

    for (const TempoChange &tempoChange : tempoMap) {
            qDebug() << "Position:" << tempoChange.position << "Tempo:" << tempoChange.tempo;
        }

    quint64 generalTiming = readMidiFileContent(fileName);
    return true;
}



int main() {
    QString path = "here path to file";
    readMidiFile(path);
    return 0;
}
```

I have 13 files for which everything is displayed correctly. For example (Example #1):

```
Position: 0 Tempo: 465116
"Some" - 33720
"many" - 236
"mi-" - 228
"nd/" - 232
"Watch-" - 930
"ing" - 236
"gon-" - 236
"na" - 236
"do/" - 217
"Easy" - 1399
"go-" - 232
"ne/" - 232
...
```

Where 33720 is time in ms from the beginning. So word "Some" will display after 33.72 seconds after beginning of the song. And word "many" will display in 236ms after word "some" will display. etc...
So here all display correctly, and same for other 12 midi files what I have.

But also I have 2 midi files which cause problems. For example (Example #2):

```
Position: 0 Tempo: 810811
Position: 39332 Tempo: 769231
Position: 42506 Tempo: 681818
"\r" - 0
"\n" - 128
"A " - 397
"cer" - 106
"tain " - 85
"smile, " - 7
"a " - 284
"cer" - 92
"tain " - 71
"face, " - 49
"\r" - 0
"can " - 7
"lead " - 85
"an " - 28
...
```

Here Letter "A " will display  in 128+397=525 ms after begining. Which is WRONG, because "A " shoud display in 20s  after begining.

Here mid files what I am using:
https://files.fm/u/ac6egv982

1. From example #1: 2 Times (Ann Lee).mid
2. From example #2: Karaoke - A Certain Smile.mid
3. Same issue like in example #2: 112561.mid

**UPD:**
I have found more files which give me same issue like in example #2. And I found one common thing in them. All of them using for line breaks "\n" and/or "\r". But all other midi files used "/". Probably something exist in that specific midi files type?

***Probably*** I don't need help with coding on QT c++, but I need help with understanding MIDI files.

Comment: You may use debugger and check if your delta logic is not handled properly. `deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);` Seems like your delta time will be reset after 10 iterations. Since 70 > 64 bytes (quint64). Either use another way to hold your time or try to handle the overflow cases.

Comment: @LouisGo just checked, and for files with timing issues - ther no iterations at all. In this place `deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);
            while (byte & 0x80) {
                trackStream >> byte;
                deltaTime = (deltaTime << 7) | (byte & 0x7F);
            }`  does not enter the cycle "while" at all.

Comment: Starts with logging on `deltaTime` and other suspicious variables and see what went wrong. Or you need an expert in midi who knows C++ to help you.